# Storyboard: Dynamic margin with contraints

Tags: objective-c, constraints, autolayout

As scribbled in the image below, I need to layout different views with fixed sizes according to the screen size. If it is the iPhone 5, the margins need to be larger than on the iPhone 4.

I've tried to accomplish this with the autolayout-contraints, but can't get this to work. Is something like this even possible with constraints? Or do I need to set up two storyboards?

Any help will be appreciated!

[image: Constraints]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one `UIView` with your preferred height (e.g. 100) and width (e.g. 100) constraints. Add align center x/y constraints. This will be your center view.

[image: center view constraints]

Add another `UIView` with your preferred height (e.g. 100) and width (e.g. 100) constraints. Add a top space (e.g. 330) to superview constraint, give it a low priority (e.g. 265). Add a vertical space constraint (e.g. 50) between your two views give it a mid priority (e.g. 825), make it a greater than or equal relation. Add two vertical space constraint (e.g. 30 and 50) with your superview, same mid priority (e.g. 825), make the bigger one less and the smalle one greater than or equal relation.

[image: lower view constraints]
[image: iphone 4 constraints]
[image: iphone 5 constraints]

Comment: Hmm indeed, I could give that a try. But I'm looking for a non-code solution, if there is one. Thought constraints are made for problems like this.

Comment: Danilo, you are a life saver. Works great, thank you very much. I was about this | | close to create a 2nd storyboard ^^